# Stanford CS106A Min / Max program

Tags: java, beginner

I am learning Java through Stanford CS106A and I'm wondering how the code for this early assignment looks.  I've worked in a proprietary scripting language before and so I'm trying to get the right programming form down for Java.  It works but am I doing anything in the wrong way?  Am I declaring and initializing my variables properly?  Is using a counter and conditional for the first instance like this good form? Am I missing a shorter, more efficient way?

```
/*
 * File: FindRange.java
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class FindRange extends ConsoleProgram {

    /* Specifies the value of the sentinel */
    private static final int SENTINEL = 0;

    public void run() {
        println("This program finds the largest and smallest numbers entered.");
        println("Enter values, one per line, using " + SENTINEL + " to signal the end of the list.");
        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            int value = readInt(" ? ");
            if (value == SENTINEL) break;
            count++;
            if (count == 1){
                min = value;
                max = value;
            }
            min = Math.min(min, value);
            max = Math.max(max, value);
        }
        if (count>0){
            println("Smallest: " + min);
            println("Largest: " + max);
        } else {
            println("No values were entered.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a proper review I think you'd need to at least reference the code from Console Program. Seems like something that was either included with the course or part of an earlier lesson.

Comment: Console Program is a part of the acm.program package that Stanford uses.  I believe it just handles the readInt and println to accept values and output the response.

Comment: I understood that much. But could you include a reference to the package download or its docs? You wouldn't want a review just taking your guess for non-runnable aspects of the code.  Especially if it includes more complex implementations you'll be using later on. As it is I'm wondering why this isn't just using built in methods.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick, you might or might not want to take it into account: put that `break` on its own line. Single-statement `if`s written on one line are confusing. Or at least separate the if from the rest with blank lines: breaking out of the `while` is important enough to warrant an extra couple of blank lines.

Comment: @s.m. Please write all suggestions for improvements in answers, not comments.

Answer (score 5):

You could initialize `min` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `max` with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, this would make the inner `if` obsolete. You could also use this for your output condition and get rid of the `count` completely.

Without knowing the complete assignment, it's hard to optimize your code in any direction.

If you don't want to use your library and do it in 'plain' Java have a look at [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor nitpick - you are using integer as a stopping condition, which means you are excluding a one perfectly acceptable input. For the sake of keeping solution simple, I would suggest to simply ask user to input number of values to compare, before reading values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

### Looping with `for`

An alternate implementation you can consider is to use a `for`-loop:

```
for (int value = readInt(" ? "); value != SENTINEL; count++, value = readInt(" ? ")) {
    min = Math.min(min, value);
    max = Math.max(max, value);
}
```

I find that it communicates the steps slightly clearer:

1. initialize `value`
2. Loop if `value != SENTINEL`
3. increment `count` and read the next input for `value`

The other minor point I can suggest is mentioned by [@mnhg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87317/27975) too, which is to initialize `min` and `max` to the appropriate default values so that you can make the comparisons immediately.

Comment: I think a `while` loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto feel free to contribute a new answer. :)